# Do you really need to version the trunk of a maven project?

Tags: maven, version-control, maven-3, branching-strategy

In a Trunk Based Development branching model, where you develop on the trunk and release from a branch, every release requires updates to POM files in both the trunk and the new branch.

For example, if the version in the trunk is set to 1.0-SNAPSHOT, the release branch needs to be updated to 1.0, and the trunk to 1.1-SNAPSHOT.

I'd really like an alternative strategy to preclude the need to update the version on the trunk, and all the associated tasks that goes with this. Thinking about it, you shouldn't really need to apply a version number to the trunk. The version number only really becomes relevant during the release process, but Maven (for a multitude of good reasons) requires a version number.

As an alternative, we could set the version on the trunk to 0.0-SNAPSHOT, which would essentially denote a special build. The problem with this though, is that it would place it before every other version, as far as Maven is concerned.

An alternative might be to use some very large number. This would at least place is after every other version, which is true if the trunk represents the tip of your development. This feels a bit arbitrary though.

The only other option I can see, is to use a string version - e.g. HEAD or LATEST, but this wouldn't conform to the latest Maven versioning scheme. Besides losing the SNAPSHOT functionality, I believe that an integer version will always be considered newer than a string (see [here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVEN/Versioning)).

So,

1. Does the theory seem sound?
2. If so, is there a better strategy out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use **TRUNK-SNAPSHOT** if you desire. This gives you "latest" resolution with a static "version".

Comment: I think this is as good as it gets. Retaining the functionality around the SNAPSHOT tag is very helpful; losing the correct ordinal comparator, since an integer version is always considered newer than a string, isn't particularly damaging.